# POSTMAN @GET Couldn't get any response and Swagger @GET The request has been terminated

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot, swagger, postman

@GET http://localhost:8080/batchConfig/findConfigs

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/batchConfig")
public class BatchJobConfigController {
    @Autowired
    private BatchJobConfigRepository repository;

    /*
     * Mapping url exmaple:http://localhost:8080/batchConfig/findConfigs
     */

    @GetMapping(value = "/findConfigs", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    List<BatchJobConfig> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    /*
     * http://localhost:8080/batchConfig/findConfigs?configId=1
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/findConfigs/{configId}", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    BatchJobConfig findOneBatchJobConfig(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new BatchJobConfigNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartBatchJobConfigurationApplication {

    Date date = new Date();

    // start everything
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartBatchJobConfigurationApplication.class, args);
    }

    // run this only on profile 'demo', avoid run this in test
    @Profile("demo")
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(BatchJobConfigRepository configRepository,
            BatchJobConfigDetailsRepository detailsRepository) {

        return args -> {
            configRepository.save(new BatchJobConfig(1L, "JAVA"));
            configRepository.save(new BatchJobConfig(2L, "CC"));
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BATCH_JOB_CONFIG")
public class BatchJobConfig2 {
    // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "BATCH_JOB_CONFIG")
    // private Set<BatchJobConfigDetails> batchJobConfigDetails;
    @Id
    private long batchJobConfigId;
    private String addUserCd;

    public BatchJobConfig2(long batchJobConfigId, String addUserCd) {
        super();
        this.batchJobConfigId = batchJobConfigId;
        this.addUserCd = addUserCd;
    }

    public long getBatchJobConfigId() {
        return batchJobConfigId;
    }

    public void setBatchJobConfigId(long batchJobConfigId) {
        this.batchJobConfigId = batchJobConfigId;
    }

    public String getAddUserCd() {
        return addUserCd;
    }

    public void setAddUserCd(String addUserCd) {
        this.addUserCd = addUserCd;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface BatchJobConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchJobConfig, Long> {

}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.root=ERROR
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
spring.profiles.active=demo
#spring.main.banner-mode=off
# Automatically update the database
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

# The database connection URL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://tetet:50002/testt

# Username
spring.datasource.username=tyyy

# Password
spring.datasource.password=rrrrr

# Define the database platform
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

# Define the naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Define the default schema
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema
```

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter=ERROR


log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper=ERROR 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

Possible reasons for the error:

Network error: the host is unreachable
Certificate problem: https is specified, but the service is using a self-signed, expired, or otherwise problematic certificate
CORS error: the requested service does not allow requests from other domains. Please try adding the Swagger Inspector Extension in chrome, since it can resolve this issue.
The Swagger Inspector Extension may be disabled. Please try enabling it by going to: chrome://extensions.

Comment: any exception or error during spring-boot app startup ?

Comment: No there is not exception. I fixed it by closing all opened command line windows. I had 3-4 CMD's opened at that time and I was killing the port i was using in this case 8080 instead of closing and reopening CMD Window.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by closing all opened Command Line Windows instead of killing the port I was using for this application.